# void / void * declaration behaviour

Tags: c, void, void-pointers

**program 1:**

```
int main()
{
    void v=8;
    printf("v=%d\n",v);
}
```

**program 2:**

```
int main()
{
    void *v=8;
    printf("*v=%u\n",*v);
    printf("v=%u\n",v);
}
```

compilation error on program 1:

```
**error**: variable or field ‘v’ declared void void v=0;
```

compilation errr on program 2:

```
**error**:invalid use of void expression printf("%d\n",*v);
```

Could anybody knows the behaviour of `void` and `void*` in the above program codes?

Comment: What do you expect either of these programs to do?  You can't just type random code and expect it to do something valid ;)

Comment: You should know what's the purpose of `void`.. Your code doesn't make sense even for studying purposes.

Comment: @prashad A compilation error is not the ‘output’ of a program.

Comment: Since both programs have an error and even fail to compile, there is no behaviour in either of the programs.

Answer (score 2):

`void` has two uses:

- Either as part of function declarations, stating that a function returns nothing, or takes no parameters.
- Or as the generic pointer type `void*`, which can be used to convert to/from any other pointer to type, without an explicit cast.

C11 6.2.5/19 states that:

> The void type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete
>   object type that cannot be completed.

This means that you cannot define variable as `void` nor dereference a `void*`.

This is stated more clearly in 6.3.2.2

> 6.3.2.2 void
>
> The (nonexistent) value of a void expression (an expression that has
>   type void) shall not be used in any way, and implicit or explicit
>   conversions (except to void) shall not be applied to such an
>   expression. If an expression of any other type is evaluated as a void
>   expression, its value or designator is discarded. (A void expression
>   is evaluated for its side effects.)

Comment: No, that does not mean you cannot declare a variable as `void`. You indeed cannot, but that is only because of a special exception that says `void` is not allowed as a variable type. Similarly, that does not say you cannot reference `void*`. Variables in general can be declared (though not defined) with incomplete types, and pointers to incomplete types can be dereferenced. The easiest example of an incomplete type for which this is clearly verifiably true is by trying it with an array of unspecified length.

Comment: And my comment was incorrect too: I stated that there was an exception disallowing `void` as a variable declaration. That's not the case. Rather, there's an exception that renders such variable declarations completely and utterly useless, by disallowing the one operation that could potentially have some use: such a variable's address cannot be taken.

Answer (score -1):

A void * is just a pointer that Points to someting you don't know.
So you can initialize ist. Even a void* isn't very useful, but it is a pointer and can be casted to a pointer of a specific type.

A void variable is "something you don't know" and so it can never be initialized and can not be declared.

Comment: There is no such thing as a void variable.

Comment: That is what I wanted to say. I added that such a variable can not be declared.